Need to print a receipt using network printer in a react Web application
I made a restaurant web application. I need to print the billing receipt in react web application using a network printer but when installing necessary libraries /packages it's not getting installed and the same error is repeating on different libraries. Need to fix this code in front-end. When I print the code the receipt design is getting printed instead the HTML code is getting printed with the tags. And I'm designing it using tailwind css. The code is connected through IP address of the printer but when the print receipt button is clicked it prints the same HTML raw code which is given as text and not printing the receipt design.
I tried packages like node-thermal-printer, npm point-of-sale, npm escpos-network but none of them are installing and showing error as Unsupported engine node version. I tried changing the node versions but still it's not getting installed. When the print receipt button is clicked it should not show the pop-up page which shows to select the printer type, print color, and etc., instead it should print the receipt directly. This should be done in webpage application.

Hey, and welcome to SO! You'll need to provide code examples please and more details about the issue you are seeing.
